# JavaScript: Changing src-attribute of a embed-tag

Tags: jquery, html, embedded-resource

I have the following scenario.

I show the user some audio files from the server. The user clicks on one, then onFileSelected is eventually executed with both the selected folder and file. What the function does is change the source from the embedded object. So in a way, it is a preview of the selected file before accepting it and save the user's choice. [A visual aid](http://gallery.me.com/sulfura#100044/embed&bgcolor=black).

HTML

```
<embed src="/resources/audio/_webbook_0001/embed_test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" id="audio_file">
```

JavaScript

```
function onFileSelected(file, directory) {
   jQuery('embed#audio_file').attr('src', '/resources/audio/'+directory+'/'+file);
};
```

Now, this works fine in Firefox, but Safari and Chrome simply refuse to change the source, regardless of Operating System.

jQuery finds the object (jQuery.size() returns 1), it executes the code, but no change in the HTML Code.

Why does Safari prevent me from changing the `<embed>` source and how can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should remove the `embed` element and reinject it with the new `src` parameter set.

`embed` like `object` and similar are two elements which, due do their special uses (video, audio, flash, activex, ...), in some browsers are handled differently from a normal DOM element. Thus changing the src attribute might not trigger the action you expect.

The best thing is to remove the existing `embed` object an reinsert it. If you write some kind of wrapper function with the src attribute as parameter this should be easy

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work somehow. It appended the new embed-tag, but did not remove the old one.

I am thinking of using a variation of this one with an iframe, but that isn't a very elegant solution.

Comment: My problem was that programmatically changing the src and calling play() still caused the original src to be played. Following this advice I now remove and re-add the embed element and the sound plays correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I was also facing same issue when I want to change "src"-attribute of "embed" element, so what I did, is given below:

```
var parent = $('embed#audio_file').parent();
var newElement = "<embed src='new src' id='audio_file'>";

$('embed#audio_file').remove();
parent.append(newElement);
```

And this will work fine in my application.

Conclusion: - You need to first remove the embed element and then you have to reinsert it with change in src.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Chrome. Alternative solution is instead of changing src of embed element, try replacing cloned embed with new src

```
$('embed').replaceWith($('embed').clone().attr('src','anotherfile.swf'));
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in Chrome, give it a star to have it fixed sooner: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69648

Answer (score 2):

Add div to embed tag,

```
 <div id="pdfId">
    <embed src="/resources/audio/_webbook_0001/embed_test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" id="audio_"/>
</div>
```

In script:

```
            var pdfId = document.getElementById("pdfId");
            pdfId.removeChild(pdfId.childNodes[0]);
            var embed = document.createElement('embed');
            embed.setAttribute('src', embedUrl);
            embed.setAttribute('type', 'audio/mpeg');
            pdfId.appendChild(embed);
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery follows the CSS-esque declaration:

Instead of doing

```
function onFileSelected(file, directory) {
   jQuery('embed#audio_file').attr('src', '/resources/audio/'+directory+'/'+file);
};
```

Rather do

```
function onFileSelected(file, directory) {
   jQuery('#audio_file').attr('src', '/resources/audio/'+directory+'/'+file);
};
```

That way, jQuery only retrieves object of id="audio_file".

Comment: seems to me your selector is "less specific" and might have a higher performance hit, can't really see the connection to your quote "CSS-esque declaration"... besides, if you read the OP, it works on some browsers but not all, so it's probably not a syntax error...

Comment: @Leon, jQuery bundles the different Javascript implementations into their library so that we (developers) don't have to worry about it. I think it's the internal usage of tags pertaining to some browsers that conflicts, so it can be syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var element = document.getElementById('element-embed');
changeSrcEmbed(element,'https://coccoc.com');
function changeSrcEmbed(element, src) {
    var id = element.id;
    element.src = src;
    var embedOld = document.getElementById(id);
    var parent = embedOld.parentElement;
    var newElement = element;
    document.getElementById(id).remove();
    parent.append(newElement);
}
```

```html
<embed id="element-embed" style="width:1100px; height: 700px;">
```