# Javascript variable in src

Tags: javascript, html, movie

I have the following Javascript variable.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("vid").src = video.url();
</script>
```

How do I put the videoUrl into my movie player.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
<embed id="vid" src="videoUrl" width="200" height="200">
</video>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Changing src-attribute of a embed-tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493706/javascript-changing-src-attribute-of-a-embed-tag)

Answer (score 2):

Get the element with javascript (after it is loaded into the DOM) then change its src attribute.

```
<embed id="vid" src="videoUrl" width="200" height="200">
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("vid").src = video.url();
</script>
```

Comment: Cannot set property of 'src' undefined.

Comment: posted the updates. video.url returns a link to a .mp4 file downloaded on a server.

Comment: the javascript MUST come after the embed. hence "after it is loaded into the DOM". is that what you did?

Comment: However, i do not get the URL until AFTER the javascript is done.

Comment: How does that work? Do you set `var video = {url : function(){...}}` later in your program?