# JavaScript programming

Tags: javascript

Why Iam unable to change the image source? here is my code

```
<script>
function changeImage() {
var image = document.getElementById("myImgId");
if (image.src.match("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\GRAPHICS\photo2.jpg")) {
    image.src="C:\Users\USER\Desktop\GRAPHICS\photo3.jpg";
} else {
    image.src="C:\Users\USER\Desktop\GRAPHICS\photo1.jpg";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Changing src-attribute of a embed-tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493706/javascript-changing-src-attribute-of-a-embed-tag)

Comment: As said already, try to escape your backslashes with another backslash like: "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\GRAPHICS\\photo3.jpg";

Answer (score 5):

Three reasons:

1. Because `\` in JavaScript strings (as in my programming languages) is an escape character, so your string doesn't actually have any backslashes in it.

   To have an actual backslash in a string literal, you need to escape it — with a backslash.
2. The `src` property is a fully-resolved URL, which will start with a protocol, in this case `file:`, and have normalized slashes (backslashes become `/` in normalized URLs).
3. `String#match` expects a regular expression. You're passing it a string, and so the string will be run through `new RegExp`, which means that even with `\\`, you still won't have backslashes in that regex because backslash is special in regexes, too (as are `.`, so that `.jpg` will be an issue). You'd need `\\\\` just to have a single literal backslash in the resulting regex.

Here's a possible fix:

```
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById("myImgId");
    if (/photo2\.jpg$/.test(image.src)) {
        image.src = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\GRAPHICS\\photo3.jpg";
    } else {
        image.src = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\GRAPHICS\\photo1.jpg";
    }
}
```

Those Windows paths will get converted to URLs on assignment.

Or perhaps you'd like to cycle through the three images:

```
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById("myImgId");
    image.src = image.src.replace(/photo(\d)\.jpg$/, function(m, c0) {
        var next = +c0 % 3 + 1;
        return "photo" + next + ".jpg";
    });
}
```

Each time you call it, that will advance to the next photo, wrapping-around from 3 to 1.

Comment: ,I want to enter the event data in the form element from the furnction to capture the mount click points.I'am using    >>>>>document.getElementById("sampleform").x=PosX; is it fine?It doesn't add the input into required field in the form <p>
    x:<input type="number"  name="x" />
   </p>